# Contador no FastReport soma mais de uma vez, como resolver?

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Tenho um relatorio bem complexo no fastreport em uma determinada página a estrutura é um MasterData -> DetailData e dentro deste Detail tenhos os requeridos componentes, funciona tudo 100%, acontece que em um fxtMemo preciso colocar o numero da planilha este irá numerar em sequencia cada planilha do Detail.

Fiz o seguinte, no codigo criei uma variavel global `ContaPlanilha: integer = 0;`

No BeforePrint do frxMemo coloco: `ContaPlanilha := ContaPlanilha +1;`

No text do frxMemo coloquei `"Planilha número: [ContaPlanilha]"`

Ele pega o valor da variavel e coloca no frxMemo como deve ser, acontece que mesmo tendo somente 1 registro teste, a variavel tem o valor setado como 2 é como se estivesse passando duas vezes no OnBeforePrint, mas como dito só tem 1 unico registro...

Estou usando "Duplo Passo" por se tratar de um relatorio complexo e preciso de alguns valores de variaveis que só estão disponiveis nessa condição

Me parece que esse "Duplo Passo" está causando esse problema, mas como criar uma variavel incremental sem que de esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, faça uso do `if Engine.FinalPass` antes de incrementar sua variável, com ele você consegue saber se está no *primeiro* ou *segundo* passo e consequentemente, pode incrementar sua variável apenas uma vez.

Comment: Matou a pau Andrey, era isso mesmo

Comment: Muito boa a resposta...